# Truffle - Is There Any Way to Auto Generate Test Cases?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, solidity, truffle

Is there any way to auto-generate test-cases in Truffle?

As an example, the [AutoFixture Library](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) was helping me to auto-generate test-cases in xUnit. I'm looking for a similar functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Truffle's tests it seems like it uses [`mocha`](https://mochajs.org/) for defining tests and [`chai`](http://www.chaijs.com/) for checking that things are OK. This is a pretty common setup in JavaScript land. It might not even be mandated, but it's a good start.

This allows you to build tests like:

```
describe('My tests', () => {
  for (const testCase of TEST_CASES) {
     it(`also works for ${testCase.name}`, () => {
        // check something about testCase
     });
  }
});
```

You can have arbitrarily many nestings of `describe`, building a tree-structure of tests. With auto-generation via the language's own features (for loops, while loops etc) you get a very powerful way of getting a lot of tests at once.

Comment: Seems like there is nothing more automated than this. I accept this answer.